# Suboptimal result of the masked vision transformer

Tags: deep-learning, transformer-model

I tried to use Huggingface to test a masked autoencoder model using pretrained weights.

I used the following code to inference it.

```
from torchvision.transforms import ToPILImage
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, SwinForMaskedImageModeling
import torch
from PIL import Image
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from transformers import AutoImageProcessor, Swinv2ForMaskedImageModeling


url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

image_processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/swinv2-tiny-patch4-window8-256")
model = Swinv2ForMaskedImageModeling.from_pretrained("microsoft/swinv2-tiny-patch4-window8-256")

num_patches = (model.config.image_size // model.config.patch_size) ** 2
pixel_values = image_processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
# create random boolean mask of shape (batch_size, num_patches)
bool_masked_pos = torch.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(1, num_patches)).bool()

outputs = model(pixel_values, bool_masked_pos=bool_masked_pos)
loss, reconstructed_pixel_values = outputs.loss, outputs.reconstruction
list(reconstructed_pixel_values.shape)

plt.imshow(((pixel_values-pixel_values.min())/(pixel_values.max()-pixel_values.min())).squeeze().permute(2,1,0).detach().numpy())
plt.show()
plt.imshow(((reconstructed_pixel_values-reconstructed_pixel_values.min())/(reconstructed_pixel_values.max()-reconstructed_pixel_values.min())).squeeze().permute(2,1,0).detach().numpy())
plt.show()
```

The result I got is not good. The loss is 1.17, and here you can see the original processed image and the output of the network.

[![original][1]][1]
[![results][2]][2]

I tried use the another pretrained model with smaller number of patches. However, the result was blury and not good. I used microsoft/swin-base-simmim-window6-192 as pretrained model.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I appreciate if you point to my potential mistakes.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M474w.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkDHw.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3YWA.png